# View array as plot in Debug mode PyCharm

Tags: python, arrays, pycharm, statistics, visualization

I have PyCharm Comunity 2019 and I am using it to develop Python scripts mostly for Machine Learning.

While working with 1D/2D arrays I liked the feature **View as Arra**y which helped me a lot while debugging.

I am wondering if a feature such as "View as Plot" exists without needing to have matplotlib code written in my script, it will help me so much to see time series data for example.

[image: This is how View as Array looks like in Debug Mode]